# ajax error 500 & Internal Server Error in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I used ajax method to call the controller and fetch the data and convert it to json or list and set a jquery `DataTable`. With 1000 records it's working fine, but when I fetch more than 5000 records, ajax method gives me:

> 500 Internal server error

Here is my code:

```
 $('#btnAllData').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'PartMaster/GridLoad',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (Result) {
            debugger;
            var pageload = Result.split('|');
            var status = (pageload[0])

            if (status == "ERROR") {
                Error(pageload[1]);

            }
            else {
                var Partdetails = (pageload[0]);
                //var LocDetails = JSON.parse(pageload[2]);

            }

            //gridDetails(status1);

        },

        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Debug your code - use your browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response which will give the details of the error) - we cannot possibly guess what it is!

Comment: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property. its through

Comment: How to solve the error Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check how much time your database is taking to returning data.
2. Set length of web response ( You can adjust the JSON response size in the web.config with ).

   ```
   <configuration>
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>  
            <webServices>                                                   
                <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000" />                 
            </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
   </configuration>
   ```

Comment: Hi Saineshwar, Thanks to replay. i tried to above code. but i got a same error. max 4 sec its retrieve data. after " return Json(listPartDetailsdetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);" its through the error

Comment: @Mani increase maxJsonLength value 50000000 and check

Comment: HI I am using below code in webconfig,I got same Error . How to fixed  it ? <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>