# Error seen when loading data in Node js application + MongoDb

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb

I am facing issue in rendering data in the UI. Using a NODE JS
application and Mongo DB is the backend.
Here is the code snippet used.

```
employee.get('/results', checkRole(), function (req, res) {
 
  employeeResultModel
    .find({})   
    .then(doc => {
      res.send(doc);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      log.error('Error occurred while fetching employee from the database', err);
    });
});
```

The mongo collection employee is having 8040 records obtained from `db.getCollection('employee').find({}).count()`

The error seen in the console are as below,

```
DataTables warning: table id=executionResult - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

Also in the debugger console

```
jQuery-3.4.1.min.js:2 GET https://localhost/ci/results?_=1607595446722 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

When loading a earlier employee collection , which contain 460 records, there is no issue seen.

I am seeking help to let me know if this issue is due the huge amount of data in the collection, due to which this failure is happening or its some issue with my code.

Indexing is already provided in the employee collection - "_id"

From the Debugger "Network" tab, could see the 15MB of data is obtained as the result of the request. Is this the cause of this error?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like few people ran into the same issue as you currently do. Looks like a limitation in server side.

I would :

- Limit the number of item send from the server to the Datatable using a pagination system.

If I can't I may :

- Change the configuration of the server in order to increase the size of AJAX responses.

But know that the second option will only delay the problem and not solve it.

---

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/39332/2-datatables-with-ajax-throwing-ajax-error-for-datasets-over-certain-size

[ajax error 500 & Internal Server Error in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250247/ajax-error-500-internal-server-error-in-mvc)

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42566/is-there-a-maximum-size-of-a-json-response

Comment: I went through the links shared about increasing the size of json response
 <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>   . Is there any option to set the json response size for a Node JS appication.

Comment: Upon a continued analysis , i was able to resolve the error. Thanks for the help..

Comment: @RahulMG I'm glad that you did! May you post what you have found in order to help an other fella with a similar issue please ?

Comment: The render code was expecting a value which was missing in the collection data. For example the collection contain employee_id, employee_name, employee_designation .But in my rendering code in js, i was trying to fetch employee_address which caused this issue..                                                       
 Sorry for posting this question as i feel this as a silly mistake and I should have analyzed more before posting this query..